# Building a tree structure JSON from flat file with JS

Tags: javascript, json, for-loop, formatting, flat-file

So I am pretty new with JS and using loops to get data formatted in a JSON tree from a flat file.
I am trying to build an SAP UI5 app and load the data into a tree table.

I have this data

```
roles: [
    { role: 'JLP', desc: "jlp role", query:"q1" },
    { role: 'JLP', desc: "jlp role", query:"q2" },
    { role: 'JLP', desc: "jlp role", query:"q3" },
    { role: 'DJF', desc: "djf role", query:"q1" },
    { role: 'DJF', desc: "djf role", query:"q2" },
    { role: 'CJ', desc: "CJ role", query:"q1" }
    ]
```

and I am trying to get it into a structure based on role

```
{
    "roles": [
        {
            "rolename": "JLP",
            "properties": [
                {
                    "role": "JLP",
                    "desc": "jlp role",
                    "query": "q1"
                },
                {
                    "role": "JLP",
                    "desc": "jlp role",
                    "query": "q2"
                },
                {
                    "role": "JLP",
                    "desc": "jlp role",
                    "query": "q3"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "rolename": "DJF",
            "properties": [
                {
                    "role": "DJF",
                    "desc": "djf role",
                    "query": "q1"
                },
                {
                    "role": "DJF",
                    "desc": "djf role",
                    "query": "q2"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "rolename": "CJ",
            "properties": [
                {
                    "role": "CJ",
                    "desc": "cj role",
                    "query": "q1"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I first build the role structure and make the overall data structure:

```
buildData:function(o){
    //find all types of roles
    var unique= [];
    for(i = 0; i < o.length; i++){
      var rolename = o[i].role;

      if(unique.indexOf(rolename)< 0) unique.push(rolename);
    }
    
    //create data structure
    var datForm ={results:{roles:[]}};
     var prop = {rolename:"",
               properties:[]};
    unique.forEach(function(a,index){
      prop.rolename = a
      datForm.results.roles.push(prop)
      prop = {rolename:"",
               properties:[]};
    });
```

Where I am struggling is when I try to loop through the data, I am having to hard code the array segments and its not working when I try to use 'i'. Its not clear to me what exactly I need to do to get the data to push the segments when it matches the role in the previously created data structure.

```
for(i = 0; i < o.length; i++){
      var current = o[i].role;
      var segment = o[i];
     
      if(current === datForm.results.roles[0].rolename) 
        datForm.results.roles[0].properties.push(segment)
      if(current === datForm.results.roles[1].rolename) 
        datForm.results.roles[1].properties.push(segment)
        if(current === datForm.results.roles[2].rolename) 
        datForm.results.roles[2].properties.push(segment)
        }

    //console.log(datForm)
    var oModel = this.getView().getModel();
    oModel.setData(datForm)
    this.getView().byId("TreeTableBasic").bindRows("/results")
```

This works, but if I use data with less or more roles it basically breaks and wont work. Can you recommend a better approach? Thanks!
Here is the example I am working on: https://jsbin.com/kovevej/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use reduce. The accumulator acts as a key/value store mapping from roles to the object representing that role. We add each input element to the `properties` array in the correct role object. Finally, we use Object.values() to get just the array of role objects in the accumulator.

```js
const data = [ { role: 'JLP', desc: "jlp role", query:"q1" }, { role: 'JLP', desc: "jlp role", query:"q2" }, { role: 'JLP', desc: "jlp role", query:"q3" }, { role: 'DJF', desc: "djf role", query:"q1" }, { role: 'DJF', desc: "djf role", query:"q2" }, { role: 'CJ', desc: "CJ role", query:"q1" } ]

const output = {
  roles: Object.values(data.reduce((a, {role, desc, query}) => (
    (a[role] ??= {rolename: role, properties: []})
      .properties.push({role, desc, query}), a), {}))
}

console.log(output)
```

Comment: Thanks this did work. I am going to study this more to learn how to use the reduce functionality. If I needed to remove additional __metadata properties that are just clutter, would I add that after the properties.push?

Comment: @user3369908 at the moment it pushes `{role, desc, query}`, but you can change that so you only push e.g. `{query}`. Read up on Javascript "destructuring" so you can fully understand the code I've written